# Big Mysql data messages, taking too long to load

Tags: mysql

Im using MySQL as Database and fetching messages via PHP, so my problem is i don't know much MySQL, and my query is taking to long to fetch the messages, my messages table has 731,847 Rows

My query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    c.from_id,
    c.to_id
FROM
    messages c
JOIN(
    SELECT CASE WHEN
        `from_id` = '15' THEN `to_id` ELSE `from_id`
END AS other,
MAX(TIME) AS latest
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    `from_id` = '15' OR `to_id` = '15'
GROUP BY
    other
) m
ON
    (
        c.from_id = '15' AND c.to_id = m.other OR c.to_id = '15' AND c.from_id = m.other
    ) AND c.time = m.latest
ORDER BY
    TIME
DESC
```

Showing rows 0 - 24 (27289 total, Query took 1.8380 seconds.)

Is there any way to improve this query, and load it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE messages;
```

If you do not have an index on your TIME field, you should add one.

Also, any additional filtering you can add via WHERE clause to reduce the number of records that are brought back is going to help it finish faster.

Once you've added the index on the time field, or if it already has one, you can append the "SHOW " keyword in front of your query and it will show you how many rows are being scanned and whether indexes are being used or not.

Comment: How can i add index on my TIME field?
I've added another WHERE clause but it takes more time:
 Showing rows 0 - 24 (27271 total, Query took 1.9032 seconds.)

Comment: ```ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD KEY `time_idx` (`time`);```

Comment: same speed again no improvements

Comment: I'm going to assume there are no indexes at all here. Run these:

```ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD KEY `from_idx` (`from_id`);
ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD KEY `to_idx` (`to_id`);```

Comment: It has lightning speed now. Thank you

Comment: Pleasure to help, glad it is fast for you now!

Comment: So now for all my tables i have to add indexes am i right?

Comment: You should consider adding indexes for fields on any table on which you will be joining or doing filtering.

Comment: i've got the same problem again, what can be the problem now? I've added the index keys. but now there are seen=0 messages when i delete them the speed increases.